# Capitalising terms like “machine learning” and “natural language processing”

Tags: computer-science, writing-style, terminology

Currently I’m proofreading my master thesis in computer science.
I am not sure about terms *machine learning* or *natural language processing.*
Is it common to write them capitalized?

Comment: Not unless George and Martha Learning had a child and named it Machine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This question is probably more apt for English Language & Usage SE.

But no, don't capitalize them. They are not proper nouns. Do capitalize "Machine Learning" if it's the name of a journal, or if it is otherwise part of the name of some entity (e.g. the International Conference on Machine Learning), but do not capitalize it when you refer to machine learning as a field.